# Proof that the MLE of logistic regression doesn't have a closed-form solution

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Maximum_likelihood_estimation_(MLE)) that the maximum likelihood estimator of logistic regression does not admit a closed form solution. Whereas, ordinary least squares regression does have a closed form solution, at least in terms of matrix inverses.

Is there a proof that logistic regression can't have a closed form solution or it is simply that none have been found after an extensive search? Proofs of the non-existence of things are presumably difficult in general.

Comment: A closed form solution is reported for binary or categorical predictors. See [Lipovetsky](https://doi.org/10.1080/02664763.2014.932760), "Analytical closed-form solution for binary logit regression by categorical predictors," Journal of Applied Statistics, 42:1, 37-49 (2015).

Comment: @Onyambu Unfortunately, that does not prove the absence of a closed form formula.  Indeed, in special cases there are explicit solutions to the likelihood equation, including models with just an intercept, models with binary-only predictors, certain "complete separation" conditions, and models with symmetries that can be exploited.  You need to define "closed form" and then demonstrate there are cases--that is, models and specific values of explanatory variables--where exhibiting a closed-form solution would contradict mathematical theorems about the nature of a solution.

Comment: The voted duplicate doesn't ask for a rigorous proof, and doesn't get one in its answer, just a claim that the equation cannot be solved.